# Are precompiled headers recursive?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Let's pretend my .h file for the creation of precompiled headers looks like the following:

*stdafx.h*

```
#include "A.h" //an external library
```

.. and "A.h" includes a bunch of other headers:

*A.h*

```
#include "B.h" //other headers from an external library included by "A.h"
#include "C.h"
//...
```

Will precompiled headers be also generated for "B.h" and "C.h" (and the header files that these two files include, and so on...), or do I have to include "B.h" and "C.h" in my "stdafx.h" also?

Comment: It will be generated, but it is a good practice to include both B.h and C.h in your stdafx.h if you are using any of the stuff declared in those files, even though they are already included in A.h

Comment: @JovanMalinovic: Why?  Surely if it's natural to include A and rely on its inclusion of B and C, that's also natural in the case of precompiled headers.  What's different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the precompiled state will include B and C.

Precompilation works by running the compiler as far as the end of stdafx.h and dumping its state to the disk, then restoring that state before compiling the body of each source file.  Everything the compiler sees when compiling stdafx.h goes into that state.

(Put it another way: the process of compiling stdafx.h is exactly the same regardless of whether you're generating the precompilation state or just compiling a source file "normally" - it's just that in the precompilation case the compiler stops at the end of the file.  It couldn't treat B and C any differently even if it wanted to.)